# C++ vector of set gives segmentation fault after performing push_back

Tags: c++, stl, vector, segmentation-fault, push-back

I have created a vector of sets in my program, and I need to go through each of the sets. In case a specific element is found in the set, I need to add a new set to the vector. However, this gives me a segmentation fault as soon as my array's counter reaches the elements that I inserted later (within the loop). In the following code, switching on list.push_back(cS) gives me a segmentation fault.

```
int main(void)  {
set<int> cS;
vector<set<int> > list;

cS.insert(1);
list.push_back(cS);

cS.insert(2);
list.push_back(cS);

for (int ctr = 0; ctr < list.size(); ctr++)
{
    for (set<int>::iterator itr = list[ctr].begin(); itr != list[ctr].end(); itr++)
    {
        if (*itr == 1 || *itr == 2)
        {
            cS.clear();
            cS.insert(3);
            //list.push_back(cS);
        }
    }
}

for (int ctr = 0; ctr < list.size(); ctr++)
{
    for (set<int>::iterator itr = list[ctr].begin(); itr != list[ctr].end(); itr++)
    {
        cout << *itr << endl;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could explain why this gives an error (in gcc).

Thank you for going through my post.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you use iterators for the set but not the vector?

Comment: Out of habit, I guess. As far as I know, for a vector, using an iterator or an index are equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `push_back` into your vector you invalidate all references to elements in it in the case the vector needs to allocate more memory. In your case the iterator `itr` becomes invalid after the `push_back`. One solution would be to add the sets to a separate list (vector) and then append them all at once after the for loop:

```
vector<set<int> > add;
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < list.size(); ctr++)
{
    for (set<int>::iterator itr = list[ctr].begin(); itr != list[ctr].end(); itr++)
    {
        if (*itr == 1 || *itr == 2)
        {
            cS.clear();
            cS.insert(3);
            add.push_back(cS);
        }
    }
}
list.insert(list.end(), add.begin(), add.end());
```

Comment: In that case, is there no way to iterate through each element of the vector, while in special cases inserting some elements to it?

Comment: `push_back` doesn't *necessarily* invalidate iterators, some call to `push_back` might invalidate.

Comment: @user571376: use index-based iteration.

Comment: The exact rules here are covered in an FAQ post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules

Comment: @user571376: yeah, there are two ways it can work. One is to store indices instead of iterators (they can always be converted back into iterators when needed). The other is to call `reserve` on the vector in advance, to ensure that `push_back` doesn't need to reallocate. But that relies on you knowing the max size of the vector in advance

Comment: @Nawaz Correct, but the only way to code is to assume it does.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck: Actually it depends. You can call `reserve` to set the maximum size if you know this in advance; then you can use `push_back` without problem. In other words, all that you need to make sure that vector doesn't reallocate memory.

Comment: Thank you Nawaz, Andreas Brinck and je4d for your solutions. They really helped, and I understood the concept of iterators a lot better.